# Error when computing mode of a DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `Date` column, I group the data by year and I can compute mean and median. But how to compute the mode? Here is the error I get:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> rng = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=10, freq='2M')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.random_integers(0,100,size=10) })
>>> df
        Date  Val
0 2010-01-31   44
1 2010-03-31   47
2 2010-05-31   64
3 2010-07-31   67
4 2010-09-30   67
5 2010-11-30    9
6 2011-01-31   83
7 2011-03-31   21
8 2011-05-31   36
9 2011-07-31   87
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A')).mean()
                  Val
Date                 
2010-12-31  49.666667
2011-12-31  56.750000
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A')).median()
             Val
Date            
2010-12-31  55.5
2011-12-31  59.5
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A')).mode()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#109>", line 1, in <module>
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A')).mode()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 554, in __getattr__
    return self._make_wrapper(attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 571, in _make_wrapper
    raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'mode' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Comment: Mode is not implemented for DataFrameGroupBy objects, as reasoned and explained here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6978.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `np.unique` with the `return_counts` parameter.
- use the `argmax` on the counts array to get value from unique array.
- use `np.apply_along_axis` for a custom function `mode`

---

```
def mode(a):
    u, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    return u[c.argmax()]

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A')).Val.apply(mode)

Date
2010-12-31    67
2011-12-31    21
Freq: A-DEC, Name: Val, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

`mode` isn't a built in function that's automatically compatible with pandas groupby objects. You could use the `scipy.stats` module. This feels a little clunky, though.

```
from scipy import stats

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A')).apply(stats.mode)
```

Alternatively, you could use the `value_counts()` function and take the first index value returned. This is the route I would go.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='A')).value_counts()[0].index.values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

[mode](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6978) is problematic as others have mentioned, however a DataFrameGroupby object can be applied a trivial lambda function, just as the AttributeError suggests using (and contains no ugly slicing or anything else):

```
df.groupby(grouping_column)[[i for i in pivotable_columns]].apply(lambda x: x.mode())]
```